# Managing Locale in Laravel 5.2, local not setting

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I'm trying to have 2 langages on my site.

So, I've translated my content, and I use this [lib](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization):

Language switcher code:

```
            <li class="dropdown language-switch">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                @if (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() =='en')
                    <img src="/images/flags/GB.png" class="position-left" alt="">
                @elseif (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() =='es')
                    <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" class="position-left" alt="">
                @else
                    <img src="/images/flags/{{LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()}}.png" class="position-left" alt="">
                @endif


                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="mexico" href="{{  LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(LaravelLocalization::setLocale('es'), Request::url()) }}"><img src="/images/flags/MX.png" alt=""> Español</a></li>
                <li><a class="english" href="{{  LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(LaravelLocalization::setLocale('en'), Request::url()) }}"><img src="/images/flags/GB.png" alt=""> English</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Thing is when I try to retrieve locale, if I do:

```
Lang::getLocale()
```

or

```
App::getLocale() // official docs
```

locale will stick to "en"

but if I do:

```
Session::get('locale')
```

it will be ok.

Thing is most of the content is translated well, but some parts are in english no matter what.

I double checked translation files, but spanish translations are available for those elements.

So, I'm a little confused about locales...

Any idea what's going on???

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization - does that help?

Comment: nop, already mentioned official docs on my post -->App::getLocale() // official docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are manually overwriting the language from your view. This also seems to be the reason that `en` is the language it always ends up with as it's the last one in the list.

Change your code to this:

```
<li><a class="mexico" href="{{  LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('es', Request::url()) }}"><img src="/images/flags/MX.png" alt=""> Español</a></li>
<li><a class="english" href="{{  LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('en', Request::url()) }}"><img src="/images/flags/GB.png" alt=""> English</a></li>
```

Comment: it worked, but I didn't undertand why :( ! Can you detail it please?

Comment: In your code you were calling `LaravelLocalization::setLocale('en')` which sets the locale on your app (like `App::setLocale()` does) and some other places. The reason it actually generated the correct language switcher URL is because it also returns the locale again. But to generate the localized URL it only needs to know the locale and not acutally set it.

Comment: but what I don't understand is that ok, url is ok, you should go to new local, but you don't set anything, so next page should go to the old local ( but it dont :), that's what I don't understand. I was doing "set and display" and now, I just do "display"

Comment: You should have something like this in your routes: `Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()...`. This is the part where it sets the locale by grabbing it of the current request url. By using `LaravelLocalization::setLocale('en')` in your view you are overwriting the language. Therefore everything that is rendered afterwards will use the English translation.

Comment: uyy you're right! in routes, I set it! I understand why it works now.

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: check your `config/app.php` file. It should have your locale (probably `es`) and your fallback (probably `en`)

Secondly: Verify if your locale identifier matches with it's requisite.

Thirdly: dump the php info by just running `phpinfo();` and look for `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`. It should be as you expect.

I Hope It's helpful!

**EDIT:**

I noticed you wrote tons of code to actually change just the file name.
Maybe it'd be cleaner if you placed it in a lang file and just call the info using the `trans()` helper or `@lang()` blade directive.

it'd be something like this:

```
<img src="/images/flags/@lang('navigation.lang.image').png" class="position-left">
```

or

```
<img src="/images/flags/{{ trans('navigation.lang.image') }}.png" class="position-left">
```

Comment: Can you please detail the second point, I don't understand it well! Tx !

Comment: Make sure you set exactly `es` and `en`, not `es-MX` or `en-US`. I was caught on it few days ago!